# Why does a BitmapImage created with CreateOptions.DelayCreation never display?

Tags: wpf, image, xaml

I would like to have an `Image` that downloads and displays only when it is first made visible. I expected `CreateOptions.DelayCreation` to have this behavior. In fact, I can observe that it *does* delay the download of the image; however, it is never actually rendered. Why?

Here is my code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfDelayCreationBug.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <BitmapImage x:Key="MySource"
                         UriSource="http://ihdwallpapers.com/download/minions-1920x1080.jpg"
                         CreateOptions="DelayCreation"
                         CacheOption="None"
                         />
            <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="Converter"/>
        </Grid.Resources>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <CheckBox x:Name="Checkbox" Content="Display image" />
        <Image Source="{StaticResource MySource}"
               Grid.Row="1"
               Visibility="{Binding ElementName=Checkbox, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource Converter}}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I would *expect* that the image should show up when I click on the check box. It doesn't! If I remove the `CreateOptions="DelayCreation"` then the image *does* show when I check the box.

Comment: If you change StaticResource to Dynamic, will it be shown?

Comment: In the [Examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapcreateoptions(v=vs.110).aspx) section `BitmapCreateOptions.DelayCreation` is used in conjunction with `BitmapCacheOption.OnDemand`. Did you try that?

Comment: Thanks for both suggestions. Sadly, neither fixes the problem. Incidentally, I could defer setting `Image.Source` until I make the image visible—so I do have a workaround for this. But I would really like to know why `DelayCreation` doesn't work as I expect.

Comment: check this out: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e3722524-de53-412c-baa9-142ac3ae31ab/bitmapcreateoptionsdelaycreation?forum=wpf
It show a piece of code working for a listbox and explains a little more about delaycreation.